# Which version of oracle should I learn as a beginner?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am beginner in Oracle. I have seen there are many oracle version such as XE, Enterprises, Personal, Liet and so on.
I would like to learn Oracle but I am very confuse which oracle version should I learn first?

Comment: I suggest you download and install the Developer Days VM.  This will get you started quickly.  [Find it here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)  You will need to install VirtualBox but that's fairly painless.

Comment: what is different between VirtualBox and XE? Is it just user interface for Oracle? Which one does it use in industry or for finding job?

Comment: VirtualBox is a virtual machine environment.  It means you can run an Oracle Enterprise Linux image with an Oracle Enterprise database on your personal machine regardless of its operating system.  XE is an actual database, so you can't install it on just any machine; Macs are out, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XE, Enetrprise, etc is not **versions**, but **editions**, like Windows Home, Professional, Ultimate.

To start learning you can begin with **Oracle 12c XE** edition.

Here you can see difference between editions:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm